# How to generalise the results of cross correlation?

Tags: time-series, multiple-comparisons, cross-correlation

**Data:** I have 1000 independent time series. Each of these 1000 contains two variables A & B.

**Goal:** My goal is to find out whether there is a statistically significant correlation between A & B for ALL 1000 time series.

**Problem:** I have performed cross-correlation for each of these 1000 time series separately and found out that in some cases A&B are indeed correlated but in some cases, they are not correlated at all.

**Question:** How should I generalise this result and make a statement about all the 1000 entries as a whole? How do I test if the few entries that are correlated are actually significant?

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "all time series"?  It sounds like you believe *some* of the series are correlated and by the usual rules of logic that implies not all time series are correlated.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @whuber. For example, let's assume 1000 are patients. A is the blood sugar level over time, and B is the obesity level over time. Now for some patients, there is a correlation between A & B but for others there is none. Does this mean that if I am asked if there is a correlation between A&B within these 1000 patients then the answer should be NO? how can I make sure that these few patients that have correlated A&B are not significant?

Comment: The answer is that there is a correlation in some patients and no correlation in others.  It is right to be concerned about the multiple comparisons issue that arises, but it's straightforward to apply a standard correction.

Comment: Sorry, could you please elaborate on what you mean by standard correction? Thank you!

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=multiple%20comparisons%20correction&searchOn=3